# CLPFD constraint: is a prime number

Tags: prolog, primes, swi-prolog, clpfd

I'm not even sure if this is possible, but I'm trying to write a predicate `prime/1` which constrains its argument to be a prime number.

The problem I have is that I haven't found any way of expressing “apply that constraint to all integers less than the variable integer”.

Here is an attempt which doesn't work:

```
prime(N) :-
    N #> 1 #/\                       % Has to be strictly greater than 1
    (
        N #= 2                       % Can be 2
        #\/                          % Or
        (
            N #> 2 #/\               % A number strictly greater than 2
            N mod 2 #= 1 #/\         % which is odd
            K #< N #/\
            K #> 1 #/\
            (#\ (
                N mod K #= 0         % A non working attempt at expressing:
                                         “there is no 1 < K < N such that K divides N”
            ))
        )
    ).
```

I hoped that `#\` would act like `\+` and check that it is false for all possible cases but this doesn't seem to be the case, since this implementation does this:

```
?- X #< 100, prime(X), indomain(X).
X = 2 ;    % Correct
X = 3 ;    % Correct
X = 5 ;    % Correct
X = 7 ;    % Correct
X = 9 ;    % Incorrect ; multiple of 3
X = 11 ;   % Correct
X = 13 ;   % Correct
X = 15     % Incorrect ; multiple of 5
…
```

Basically this unifies with `2\/{Odd integers greater than 2}`.

#### EDIT

Expressing that a number is **not prime** is very easy:

```
composite(N) :-
    I #>= J,
    J #> 1,
    N #= I*J.
```

Basically: “`N` is composite if it can be written as `I*J` with `I >= J > 1`”.

I am still unable to “negate” those constraints. I have tried using things like `#==>` (implies) but this doesn't seem to be implification at all! `N #= I*J #==> J #= 1` will work for composite numbers, even though `12 = I*J` doesn't imply that necessarily `J = 1`!

Comment: There are remaining constraints that are not displayed on the toplevel. Use **`call_residue_vars/2`** to see them: `?- call_residue_vars((X #< 100, prime(X), indomain(X)), Vs).`

Comment: @mat So from what I see I get the problem that I expected, which is that it only checks that there is at least one integer which doesn't divide `N`, when i want it to check that for all integers between `2` and `N-1`. I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: @Fatalize, Do you want only with clpfd??because i think you could write a presicate that give prime numbers more easily...

Comment: @coder Yes. I don't want to try iteratively integers until I find the right one is further expressions, I want to have a variable which is constrained to be a prime. As I have said I don't even know if this is possible outside my answer (which only says *the number must be in this set of primes*)

Comment: What do you mean constrait to be a prime. If you write a predicate prime(X) which returns X=2,3,5.... whithout clpfd wouldn't be the same??

Comment: @coder Well no, because I don't want `prime` to return `2,3,…` I want it to constraint `X` (and "return" `2,3,…` when labeling). Otherwise that would be like using `between(1,100000,I),152399025 is I*I` (24k inferences) instead of `X*X #= 152399025` (584 inferences).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `prime/1`

This took me quite a while and I'm sure it's far from being very efficient but this seems to work, so here goes nothing:

We create a custom constraint propagator (following [this example](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=clpfd-custom-constraints)) for the constraint `prime/1`, as such:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
:- multifile clpfd:run_propagator/2.

prime(N) :-
    clpfd:make_propagator(prime(N), Prop),
    clpfd:init_propagator(N, Prop),
    clpfd:trigger_once(Prop).

clpfd:run_propagator(prime(N), MState) :-
    (
        nonvar(N) -> clpfd:kill(MState), prime_decomposition(N, [_])
        ;
        clpfd:fd_get(N, ND, NL, NU, NPs),
        clpfd:cis_max(NL, n(2), NNL),
        clpfd:update_bounds(N, ND, NPs, NL, NU, NNL, NU)
    ).
```

**If `N` is a variable**, we constrain its lower bound to be `2`, or keep its original lower bound if it is bigger than `2`.

**If `N` is ground**, then we check that `N` is prime, using this `prime_decomposition/2` predicate:

```
prime_decomposition(2, [2]).
prime_decomposition(N, Z) :-
    N #> 0,
    indomain(N),
    SN is ceiling(sqrt(N)),
    prime_decomposition_1(N, SN, 2, [], Z).

prime_decomposition_1(1, _, _, L, L) :- !.
prime_decomposition_1(N, SN, D, L, LF) :-
    (   
        0 #= N mod D -> !, false
        ;
        D1 #= D+1,
        (    
            D1 #> SN ->
            LF = [N |L]
            ;
            prime_decomposition_2(N, SN, D1, L, LF)
        )
    ).

prime_decomposition_2(1, _, _, L, L) :- !.
prime_decomposition_2(N, SN, D, L, LF) :-
    (   
        0 #= N mod D -> !, false
        ;
        D1 #= D+2,
        (    
            D1 #> SN ->
            LF = [N |L]
            ;
            prime_decomposition_2(N, SN, D1, L, LF)
        )
    ).
```

You could obviously replace this predicate with any deterministic prime checking algorithm. This one is a modification of a prime factorization algorithm which has been modified to fail as soon as one factor is found.

### Some queries

```
?- prime(X).
X in 2..sup,
prime(X).


?- X in -100..100, prime(X).
X in 2..100,
prime(X).


?- X in -100..0, prime(X). 
false.


?- X in 100..200, prime(X).
X in 100..200,
prime(X).


?- X #< 20, prime(X), indomain(X).
X = 2 ;
X = 3 ;
X = 5 ;
X = 7 ;
X = 11 ;
X = 13 ;
X = 17 ;
X = 19.

?- prime(X), prime(Y), [X, Y] ins 123456789..1234567890, Y-X #= 2, indomain(Y).
X = 123457127,
Y = 123457129 ;
X = 123457289,
Y = 123457291 ;
X = 123457967,
Y = 123457969
…


?- time((X in 123456787654321..1234567876543210, prime(X), indomain(X))).
% 113,041,584 inferences, 5.070 CPU in 5.063 seconds (100% CPU, 22296027 Lips)
X = 123456787654391 .
```

### Some problems

This constraint does not propagate as strongly as it should. For example:

```
?- prime(X), X in {2,3,8,16}.
X in 2..3\/8\/16,
prime(X).
```

when we should know that `8` and `16` are not possible since they are even numbers.

I have tried to add other constraints in the propagator but they seem to slow it down more than anything else, so I'm not sure if I was doing something wrong or if it is slower to update constaints than check for primeness when labeling.

Comment: Good solution, +1! As a rule of thumb, I would recommend against propagations that are worst-case *linear* in the size of the domain (in this case: pruning within the domain), because this means exponential-time propagation. Other comments: Some `!/0` are unnecessary! Using `zcompare/3` is better (more general) than if-then-else. In fact, none of those constructs are necessary in your case, because you can write `0 #\= N mod D`! One important point: `ceiling(sqrt(N))` will *overflow* for larger integers. I recommend to **avoid** `(is)/2` for such reasons. Use constraints instead!

Comment: That being said, it is indeed customary to at least maintain *bounds* consistency, which means to ensure that at least the boundaries are consistent with the constraint. In the example you give, this would first eliminate 16, and on re-triggering eliminate 8, so that in this concrete case even only the prime elements remain. Since there are arbitrarily large gaps between primes, implementing this in this case leads to worst-case exponential behaviour though. A key advantage of constraints, to make the core relation efficient while putting the tough part in the labeling would thus be gone...